# Upgrading CAS 4.0.0 to 4.2.x

Tags: cas

When I started with CAS I ran into a problem which lead to a white screen on my CAS server. I didn't know why so I tried another version and used 4.0.0 instead of 4.2.x. And all of the sudden it worked. But I decided that I want to the newest version of CAS and tried to upgrade my project. I still have the same problem of course. When I open the CAS server I get the following exception:

```
2016-09-15 09:37:31,563 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - <Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'centralAuthenticationService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ticketRegistry' is defined
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1795)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ticketRegistry' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:512)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:615)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
        ... 26 more
>
```

So I checked what is in my `war`file of my cas server and to my supprise I found out that the `deployerConfigContext.xml`file is not the file that I used.

This is my `deployerConfigContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
| deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
| all CAS deployers will need to modify.
|
| This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.
| The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring
| ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
| file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
|
| By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
| declaration to replace the default authentication handler with
| one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
+-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:map id="authenticationHandlersResolvers">
        <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
        <entry key-ref="primaryAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="primaryPrincipalResolver" />
    </util:map>

    <util:list id="authenticationMetadataPopulators">
        <ref bean="successfulHandlerMetaDataPopulator" />
        <ref bean="rememberMeAuthenticationMetaDataPopulator" />
    </util:list>

    <bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.NamedStubPersonAttributeDao"
          p:backingMap-ref="attrRepoBackingMap" />

    <alias name="acceptUsersAuthenticationHandler" alias="primaryAuthenticationHandler" />
    <alias name="personDirectoryPrincipalResolver" alias="primaryPrincipalResolver" />

    <util:map id="attrRepoBackingMap">
        <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
        <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" />
        <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
        <entry>
            <key><value>memberOf</value></key>
            <list>
                <value>faculty</value>
                <value>staff</value>
                <value>org</value>
            </list>
        </entry>
    </util:map>

    <alias name="serviceThemeResolver" alias="themeResolver" />

    <alias name="jsonServiceRegistryDao" alias="serviceRegistryDao" />

    <alias name="defaultTicketRegistry" alias="ticketRegistry" />

    <alias name="ticketGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy" alias="grantingTicketExpirationPolicy" />
    <alias name="multiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy" alias="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" />

    <alias name="anyAuthenticationPolicy" alias="authenticationPolicy" />
    <alias name="acceptAnyAuthenticationPolicyFactory" alias="authenticationPolicyFactory" />

    <bean id="auditTrailManager"
          class="org.jasig.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager"
          p:entrySeparator="${cas.audit.singleline.separator:|}"
          p:useSingleLine="${cas.audit.singleline:false}"/>

    <alias name="neverThrottle" alias="authenticationThrottle" />

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
        <ref bean="memoryMonitor" />
        <ref bean="sessionMonitor" />
    </util:list>

    <alias name="defaultPrincipalFactory" alias="principalFactory" />
    <alias name="defaultAuthenticationTransactionManager" alias="authenticationTransactionManager" />
    <alias name="defaultPrincipalElectionStrategy" alias="principalElectionStrategy" />
    <alias name="tgcCipherExecutor" alias="defaultCookieCipherExecutor" />

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="pooled" value="true"/>
            <property name="urls">
                <list>
                    <value>ldap://localhost:389</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="userDn" value="uid=admin,ou=system"/>
            <property name="password" value="secret"/>
            <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.FastBindLdapAuthenticationHandler" >
        <property name="filter" value="uid=%u,ou=system" />
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegisteredServiceImpl">
           <property name="id" value="0" />
           <property name="name" value="HTTP" />
           <property name="description" value="Only Allows HTTP Urls" />
           <property name="serviceId" value="https://**" />
           <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
           <property name="enabled" value="true" />
           <property name="allowedToProxy" value="true" />
           <property name="ssoEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

And this is the `deployerConfigContext.xml` that was in my `war` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
| deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
| all CAS deployers will need to modify.
|
| This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.
| The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring
| ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
| file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
|
| By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
| declaration to replace the default authentication handler with
| one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
+-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key-ref="ldapAuthenticationHandler" value="#{null}"/>
                <entry key-ref="proxyAuthenticationHandler" value-ref="proxyPrincipalResolver" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="authenticationPolicy">
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AnyAuthenticationPolicy" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism. -->
    <bean id="proxyAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
          p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />

    <!-- Required for proxy ticket mechanism -->
    <bean id="proxyPrincipalResolver"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.BasicPrincipalResolver" />

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
          class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
          p:principalIdAttribute="cn"
          c:authenticator-ref="ldapAuthenticator">
      <property name="principalAttributeMap">
        <map>
          <entry key="member" value="member" />
          <entry key="mail" value="mail" />
          <entry key="displayName" value="displayName" />
        </map>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthenticator" class="org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator"
          c:resolver-ref="dnResolver"
      c:handler-ref="ldapAuthHandler" />

    <bean id="dnResolver"
          class="org.ldaptive.auth.FormatDnResolver"
          c:format="cn=%s,${ldap.baseDn}" />

    <bean id="ldapAuthHandler" class="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler"
          p:connectionFactory-ref="pooledLdapConnectionFactory" />

    <bean id="pooledLdapConnectionFactory"
          class="org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
          p:connectionPool-ref="connectionPool" />

    <bean id="connectionPool"
          class="org.ldaptive.pool.BlockingConnectionPool"
          init-method="initialize"
          p:poolConfig-ref="ldapPoolConfig"
          p:blockWaitTime="${ldap.pool.blockWaitTime}"
          p:validator-ref="searchValidator"
          p:pruneStrategy-ref="pruneStrategy"
          p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" />

    <bean id="ldapPoolConfig" class="org.ldaptive.pool.PoolConfig"
          p:minPoolSize="${ldap.pool.minSize}"
          p:maxPoolSize="${ldap.pool.maxSize}"
          p:validateOnCheckOut="${ldap.pool.validateOnCheckout}"
          p:validatePeriodically="${ldap.pool.validatePeriodically}"
          p:validatePeriod="${ldap.pool.validatePeriod}" />

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.ldaptive.DefaultConnectionFactory"
          p:connectionConfig-ref="connectionConfig" />

    <bean id="connectionConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ConnectionConfig"
          p:ldapUrl="${ldap.url}"
          p:connectTimeout="${ldap.connectTimeout}"
          p:useStartTLS="${ldap.useStartTLS}" />

    <!-- needs review, tired of fighting it
      p:sslConfig-ref="sslConfig" />
    <bean id="sslConfig" class="org.ldaptive.ssl.SslConfig">
      <property name="credentialConfig">
        <bean class="org.ldaptive.ssl.X509CredentialConfig"
              p:trustCertificates="${ldap.trustedCert}" />
      </property>
    </bean>
    -->

    <bean id="pruneStrategy" class="org.ldaptive.pool.IdlePruneStrategy"
          p:prunePeriod="${ldap.pool.prunePeriod}"
          p:idleTime="${ldap.pool.idleTime}" />

    <bean id="searchValidator" class="org.ldaptive.pool.SearchValidator" />

    <!--
    Sample, in-memory data store for the ServiceRegistry. A real implementation
    would probably want to replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO
    The name of this bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao".
    +-->
    <bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
            p:registeredServices-ref="registeredServicesList" />

    <util:list id="registeredServicesList">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
              p:id="0" p:name="HTTP and IMAP" p:description="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols"
              p:serviceId="^(https?|imaps?)://.*" p:evaluationOrder="10000001" />
    </util:list>

    <bean id="auditTrailManager" class="com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager" />

    <bean id="healthCheckMonitor" class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.HealthCheckMonitor" p:monitors-ref="monitorsList" />

    <util:list id="monitorsList">
      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.MemoryMonitor" p:freeMemoryWarnThreshold="10" />
      <!--
        NOTE
        The following ticket registries support SessionMonitor:
          * DefaultTicketRegistry
          * JpaTicketRegistry
        Remove this monitor if you use an unsupported registry.
      -->
      <bean class="org.jasig.cas.monitor.SessionMonitor"
          p:ticketRegistry-ref="ticketRegistry"
          p:serviceTicketCountWarnThreshold="5000"
          p:sessionCountWarnThreshold="100000" />
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

I have the feeling that the problem might be that I get a "wrong" `deployerConfigContext.xml`file and thats why he can't find the bean.

The only thing that I change is that I changed is the version of CAS in the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd ">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-overlay</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>cas</warName>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>WEB-INF/cas.properties</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>github-cas</finalName>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-server-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${cas.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
             <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
             <version>${cas.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <cas.version>4.2.0</cas.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the `deployerConfigContext.xml` was inside the wrong path.

Comment: Which was the right one? Regards!